# Перенос ОС на SSD

Tags: windows-10, ос, ssd

Недавно у меня возникла мысль купить SSD. Небольшой на 120 гигов, чисто для ОС. Но вот есть проблема. У меня на Диске C вместе с системой лежит много файлов ( в основном всё занимает папка пользователи). Естественно на SSD всё не влезет. В интернете видел только варианты с переносом всего диска C на SSD.А мне нужно только ОС.
Возможно кто - нибудь подскажет, как можно это реализовать или хотя бы кинет ссылку.
`OS windows 10`

Comment: Какой производитель?

Comment: @AntonSorokin ещё не определился. А есть разница?

Comment: Зачем файлы пользователя хранить на ssd? Храните их на hdd, пусть на sdd будут критично важные файлы приложений и системные файлы.

Comment: @Anamnian я же написал. Мне SSD нужен для переноса на него операционки. Пользователь папка пользователи должна остаться на hdd.

Comment: @Anamnian, так он и спрашивает, как только ОС перенести, а файлы оставить.

Comment: Скинуть файлы пользователя в облако (временное хранилище). Стереть файлы пользователя с диска. Перенести ОС. Скачать файлы пользователя из облака обратно на диск.

Comment: @Qwertiy пункт про только ОС появился после отправки моего комментария.

Comment: Вот это `Небольшой на 120 гигов, чисто для ОС` было ещё до. Но впринципе не суть.

Comment: @Anamnian, ну, оно там подразумевалось, хотя в явном виде выглядит позаметнее.

Comment: Не знаю, по моему мой способ хоть и костыльный, но рабочий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способ такой - у вас все равно не будет 2 диска С. Поэтому вы должны перенести файлы пользователя(и т.п.) на диск D на HDD. Сделать можно по [это инструкции](https://vellisa.ru/how-transfer-folder-another-disk). Потом удаляете все файлы пользователей, и переносите C(Windows) с HDD на SSD. По одной из [этих инструкций](https://it-like.ru/kak-perenesti-windows-7-na-ssd-disk/).

Потом удаляете диск C на HDD, загружаетесь с SSD и в кач-ве D используете HDD. Если у вас нет второго разъема - то просто удалите папку пользователей, почистите систему, и переносите на SSD(т.е. вы не используете HDD).

**UPD:** Еще способ: можно перенести файлы пользователя на D, а на SSD заново переустановить систему. Как по мне, так лучший способ, т.к. нужные файлы сохраняются, а система будет чистая и не будет тормозить.

Comment: У меня пк. Так что разъёмов хватит)

Comment: Кстати, возможно ли переустановить ОС на SSD Без потери файлов (через setup в загрузочной флешке)?

Comment: Если создать загрузочную флешку и запустить на ней setup.exe, то будут предложены варианты наподобие удалить всё, сохранить файлы или сохранить файлы и приложения. Возможно ли из этого приложения указать новое расположение системы.

Comment: @TOS если перенести систему на SSD, а потом запустить setup.exe  и нажать сохранить файлы(и приложения), то да. А если с hdd, то не знаю.